# How common are films with a variable frame rate?

Tags: film-techniques

*Avatar: The Way of Water* uses 48 FPS for "fast moving" scenes and drops to 24 FPS (with duplicated frames) for others ([source](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/01/02/movies/avatar-the-way-of-water-high-frame-rate.html)). [Wikipedia's list of HFR films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_with_high_frame_rates) doesn't mention any others.

I'm aware that [the Mind's Eye series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind%27s_Eye_(film_series)) (home video -only; DVD, VHS, Laserdisc), compilations of early CGI renders, appears to present the shorts in their original frame rate. I believe that the films mix 12 FPS, 15 FPS, [24p](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24p), 30p and 30i (interlaced) content.

Comment: To answer the title, not many. The second paragraph is talking about something else. The third doesn't happen. You have like three different topics going on, mixed with confusion about what you're asking or the concept of what you're asking.

Comment: Also you're wrong about minds eye release, for you to watch it, it would've been whatever the standard was for television in your region. Also in the cinema the projection would've been a fixed frame rate. The frame rate of the content is irrelevant.

Comment: I recall Band of Brothers using a variable fps [but lowering it, not raising it] in the action sequences, to mimic on a digital shoot what using a 45° shutter did on Saving Private Ryan. My recall is hazy, I think it must have been mentioned in the making of DVD which came in the box set. I can't find any reference to it online & no longer have a DVD player :\

Comment: In *Babylon 5* the synthetic scenes are 24fps and the live action 30fps, if I remember right.

Comment: @blobbymcblobby The third paragraph should likely be taken out (and the "at home" point is unnecessary). The post is indeed misleading, I've assumed that a title's frame rate is fixed and any sections running at a lower rate have each frame displayed several times (as with Avatar 2).

Comment: `mediainfo` reports 29.970fps for my NTSC DVD rip of 'Beyond the Mind's Eye', suggests interlaced 30i.

Comment: As already mentioned, a DVD release is going to be at your national broadcast standard frame rate. 29.97 is standard US 'drop frame' used in NTSC broadcast. If you'd bought the EU PAL release it would show as 25 [if you owned dual-standard-capable hardware, which was rare at the time]. SD  frame rates were normally hard-tied to your TV's refresh-rate capability, which would be factory-set. Only in recent years have we had screens that can adapt their refresh rate to match a source's frame rate.

Comment: Home video on DVD or VHS is irrelevant. the question should really be about the original digital or film *source* where variable rates are possible and non-standard rates have been used, if infrequently.